# AWS SDK JAVA 2.x. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

After upgrading AWS SDK java 1.9 version to 2.10.4, I am facing issue. We have an administrator IAM role and it has the necessary permission to run your SDK operations. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY has been configured on server.However, when I try to read, upload , copy ,delete the content in S3 Bucket , I get below exception:

```
Error while uploading the file to S3 :
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403)
```

Logs are as below:

```
2019-12-09 06:57:38,578[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory - socket.getSupportedProtocols(): [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2], socket.getEnabledProtocols(): [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2019-12-09 06:57:38,578[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory - TLS protocol enabled for SSL handshake: [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
2019-12-09 06:57:38,591[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.net.SdkSslSocket - created: s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/52.218.84.98:443
2019-12-09 06:57:38,599[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.net.SdkSslSocket - shutting down output of s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/52.218.84.98:443
2019-12-09 06:57:38,599[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.net.SdkSslSocket - closing s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/52.218.84.98:443
2019-12-09 06:57:38,601[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Received error response: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: E7487335BF54C09A)
2019-12-09 06:57:38,601[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.core.retry.ClockSkew - Reported service date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 06:57:38 GMT
2019-12-09 06:57:38,601[http-bio-8093-exec-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.core.retry.ClockSkew - Reported service date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 06:57:38 GMT
2019-12-09 06:57:38,603[http-bio-8093-exec-1] ERROR com.helper.ComponentBackendHelper - Error while uploading the file to S3 :
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: E7487335BF54C09A)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleErrorResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:115) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44) ~[sdk-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55) ~[aws-core-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.putObject(DefaultS3Client.java:3056) ~[s3-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at com.helper.ComponentBackendHelper.uploadToS3Bucket(ComponentBackendHelper.java:1179) [classes/:na]
        at com.helper.ComponentBackendHelper.uploadGenericHtmlDoc(ComponentBackendHelper.java:1353) [classes/:na]
        at com.helper.ComponentBackendHelper.uploadDAGTFileToS3Bucket(ComponentBackendHelper.java:406) [classes/:na]
        at com.helper.BackendAPIHelper.getComponentDeploymentJob(BackendAPIHelper.java:3178) [classes/:na]
        at com.service.BackendService.compdeploy(BackendService.java:639) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) [jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
```

Could you please help me out here.